# Updating UI Activity in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

here is my problem.  I am programming an android app, which needs to display the time the activity it is running.  Therefor I created a new Thread which is called from the activity.  However when I start the app in the emulator, it seems the Activity is never loaded.  Maybe you guys can help me here.  Here is the relevant code:

```
public class ActivityStartTracker extends ActivityBasic {
    TimerThread timer;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        timer = new TimerThread();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ServiceLocator.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        timer.run();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.interrupt();
        }
    }

    class TimerThread extends Thread {
        boolean isRunning = false;

        public TimerThread() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int seconds = 0;
            isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Timer is running for : " + seconds);
                    seconds++;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return isRunning;
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, these are the relevant code fragments.
The problem is, if I run this, the Activity stays black - I just get the header with the name of the app, thats all.  With the logging I can confirm that the thread is running, but nothing else is displayed.

Can you please help me out, I am rather new to android.
Thank you very much - already in advance.

Comment: hy! i don't see a code where you change the gui? i you want to update the gui in the thread you have to use `runOnUIThread()`

Comment: Thats true - The GUI was working perfectly before I tried adding the new feature displaying the timer - therefor I figured I could remove all the findView() and setText() Methods.  I just wanted to display the core of the problem - so you guys dont have to read all the unnecessary codelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep on your mind that the only thread that can update the UI is the `UIThread` .

So if you want to modify the UI in another thread, you should the method : `runOnUIThread()`

, but when you have a thread that will update the UI , the best way is to use `AsyncTask` ; refer [this](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/908-tutorial-progressbar-running-in-asynctask)

Answer (score 1):

Calling timer#run() will do just that, call the #run() method in the UI thread. You need to start your thread by calling #start() on it instead - the new thread will then do what you expect.

**Further:** Do not ever call Thread#start() twice, it won't actually restart the thread, just crash your application. If you intend to start the Thread from your onResume you need to allocate a new thread there.

Btw, consider using an AsyncTask instead.

Br,
Jens

Comment: I thought of AsyncTask as well, however it is for displaying the seconds the activity is running, and I could not figure out how to make an AsynTask running in a while()-loop and then putting it to sleep for one second.  BTW... thank you for your quick help - it works.

Comment: Handlers work well for timers. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html